# Avoiding placing `,\,` everywhere in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, punctuation

Whenever I write ", " (with a space after the comma) in mathmode, I *really* want a space there. usually, this is either something like

> the points, $a, b$, and $c$....

or in an explicit vector:

> Let the vector $x=(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ be...

Since TeX removes this space, my text is often riddled with explicit short spaces: `$x_1,\,x_2,\,x_3)$`.

Is there a way to tell TeX that this is not desirable or to hack TeX into submission?

Comment: I've asked a related question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8047/215

Answer (score 23):

This is kind of a non-answer, but here's what I'd do. For vectors, I'd always just use

```
Let the vector $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ be ...
```

In math mode, TeX inserts a thin space after the `,` (`\thinmuskip`, as Lev points out in his answer), and I find that exactly right. In your other example, I'd write

```
the points $a$, $b$, and~$c$ ...
```

(with or without the `,` after `$b$`), and this is also what Knuth recommends in the TeXbook. (Note the tie after `and`!) This yields correct spacing; moreover, it allows a linebreak after `$a$`.

Comment: Right. There is some space after a comma in math mode, even if it's not how much you wanted.

Comment: Indeed, the point here is that the comma has textual rather than mathematical meaning, and so should _not_ be in math mode.

Comment: @Joseph: Is your comment addressed to me or to Ben? (I'm no sure what you mean by _here_.)

Comment: @Hendrik. To Ben: sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: I concede on the $a$, $b$, and $c$. And while I understand that it goes against the very grain of TeXBook, I was wondering, if and how I could make that space a little bit larger...

Comment: @Yossi: Which of the spaces do you want to make larger?

Comment: @Yossi: maybe `\mathsurround=1pt`?

Comment: @morbusg: I don't like it since it adds space _before_ the comma in `$a$, $b$`.

Comment: @Joseph: I was actually talking about the spacing in the vector. I do realize that for a, b, c, the way Hendrik suggested is correct.

Answer (score 7):

You can change the size of the skip after commas, semicolons and `\colon`s (`\mathpunct`) by changing `\thinmuskip`, eg. `\thinmuskip=5mu`, but thin spaces are used in many other places so this is not a great solution.

You could make the comma an active character in mathmode (see, eg, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/substituting-character-l-with-ell-throughout-math-mode/1990#1990)), but this could maybe cause compatibility problems with some packages.

Personally I would do as Hendrik said, enter your first example as

```
the points $a$, $b$, and~$c$ ...
```

and not mess with TeX's spacing for the second example (your version with the explicit thin spaces looks too big to me, although I accept that my judgement on these things has been calibrated by working with TeX so much).

Answer (score 5):

In LuaTeX you can control the spacing between objects for each pair of classes individually:

```
Let the vector $x=(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ be\par
\Umathpunctordspacing\textstyle=20mu
Let the vector $x=(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ be
\bye
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not correct mathematical typesetting, but you can increase the spaces after commas with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\Vec#1{\expandafter\Vec@i#1,,\@nil}
\def\Vec@i#1,#2,#3\@nil{%
  $#1\ifx\relax#2\relax$\else,\mkern\thickmuskip$%
  \Vec@i#2,#3\@nil\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Let the vector \Vec{x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)} be...

and can simply be reverted 
\let\Vec\ensuremath

Let the vector \Vec{x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)} be...

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to make your answer clearer. Please revert my edit if it isn't OK.

Comment: @Hendrik: thanks and happy new year :-)