# Spacing around \text{} in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Inspired by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8041/215), here's my mathmode spacing bugbear.

I quite often have equations that look like this:

```
\begin{equation}
  \text{If}\ B_1 \succeq B_2 \ \text{and}\ B_2 \succeq B_3 \ \text{then}\ B_1 \succeq B_3
\end{equation}
```

Now, you might notice that before and after each bit of `\text{...}` there is a "normal sized space". I can't imagine why I wouldn't want that space there, but I have to add it manually. Surely this should be the default behaviour of mathmode's text macro?

Why isn't it, and how could I make it so?

Comment: I usually add a space inside the `\text` (like `\text{ and }`). Is this wrong?

Comment: I read somewhere that given that it's wrapped in mathmode, it's preferable to let mathmode do the spacing. Either way, you're adding the space explicitly...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not the default behavior because you don't always want space.  For instance, in your example, you *don't* want space before `\text{If}`, since that would indent your equation.  Or consider

```
\[ x = \begin{cases}
         1 & \text{if $f(x)$}
         0 & \text{otherwise}
       \end{cases} \]
```

Again, that shouldn't be spaced out.  Also, like in [Caramdir's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/spacing-around-text-in-mathmode/8049#8049), I re-entered math mode within the `\text`, which often solves the spacing problems as well.  You could define an `\stext` command for spaced out text:

```
\newcommand*{\stext}[1]{\text{ #1 }}
```

(Literal spaces inside are the same as `\`  outside, I believe.)  Another option might be

```
\newcommand*{\textop}[1]{\mathbin{\text{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\textrel}[1]{\mathrel{\text{#1}}}
```

Then `\textop{foo}` would set `foo` as a binary operator, and `\textrel{bar}` would set `bar` as a binary relation.  I'm not sure how this spacing would look, though, but it might work for what you want.

Answer (score 13):

It probably doesn't add space because it is harder to remove space than to add space. One possible usage is something like `3-\text{connected graphs}`.

Side remark: It is also possible to write your example as

```
\begin{equation}
  \text{If $B_1 \succeq B_2$ and $B_2 \succeq B_3$ then $B_1 \succeq B_3$.}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Maybe even better: replace `equation` with `center` and remove the `\text`.  Unless the OP really wants this sentence numbered like an equation.

Comment: I do, it's a property of a relation that I want to refer back to by a `\tag`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to introduce automatic spacing before or after `\text`, your best option is probably to make `\text` behave like an operator (`\mathop`), which is the closest thing to text inside math mode. The spacing introduced will be slightly smaller than normal text, but should still be acceptable. Here's the code (making sure that `\text` still works in text mode):

```
\newcommand{\textop}[1]{\relax\ifmmode\mathop{\text{#1}}\else\text{#1}\fi}
```

If you compare this to the respective commands `\textbin` and `\textrel` which are of type `\mathbin` and `\mathrel` (suggested in Antal's answer), you see that it works quite well in these typical uses of `\text`, even if the spacing is tight:

[image]

These commands also all fail at the begining of an `{align}` (e.g. `\begin{align} & \text{...}`):

[image]

(The order of each command is the same as above.)