# Spacing in displayed equations with a piece of text in the middle

Tags: math-mode, spacing

In order to avoid an excess of symbolism, I like to typeset displayed equations with some text replacing some connective, as in

```
(\forall x\in \mathbb{N}: \{1,\dots,x-1\} \subseteq B) 
           \rightarrow x\in B\quad \text{implies} \ B=\mathbb{N}.
```

[image: equation with text in the middle]

As you can read, I had to insert some spaces manually in the code. To obtain pleasant-looking results, these spaces might depend, for instance, on the length of the formulas on each side (in this example, I needed a `\quad` before and a `\` after the piece of text, but I'm not really happy with the result).

I found some related questions, like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8047), but nothing exactly like this.

> Is there any way of doing this automatically (and more *correctly*, for that matter)?

Comment: when a `\text` inclusion appears within a "math" line of a display, the spacing can be placed inside the `\text` string.  it's a bit more obvious there, and therefore may be easier to recognize and adjust.  most of the "named" space commands work equally well in math or text.  i can't think of any way to set this spacing automatically.

Comment: \newcommand{\mytext}[1]{\quad\text{#1}\quad} ?   I always put \quads both before and after text.  I also tend to move things like "implies B=N" to the paragraph so as not to end a sentence in display math.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've tried that several times, but the cleanest thing to do, `\text{ text }`, does not add sufficient space for a displayed equation.

Comment: @JohnKormylo The point is that I'm not so sure that just a `\quad` is always enough, nor the same spacing on both sides. Also, here I'm considering my example as an _equation_, but rather written in another style; so it should not be considered as text.

Comment: i didn't mean to limit the space to `\text{ text }`.  what i did mean is that `\text{\qquad text\quad}` or any other reasonable combination is possible.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you; I got it that way, but it still has a very ad hoc character.