# Math-mode aware search/replace utility?

Tags: math-mode, tools, sourcecode

As I gradually update the source code of my LaTeX documents to conform to new conventions, I find myself in need of a search/replace utility that is (or can be made) aware of LaTeX math mode. Often I need to replace some patterns in math mode, but not in text mode.

For example, my own stubborn TeX trickery once made me turn `.` into a math-active alias for `\cdot`. It made my math code a lot more readable at the time. Now that I'm using XeLaTeX and unicode input, I want to replace those occurrences with a proper `·`.

Using regular expressions in a conservative way, I've been able to catch a lot of them, but now and then I still run into some stragglers. If only I could automatically replace all `.`'s *in math mode*, it would save me a lot of tedious effort. And there are still two or three more of such cases.

Math mode in my documents is relatively predictable. Always delimited by `\[...\]`, `$...$` or one of a small number of custom environments. I also occasionally use `\text`. But it doesn't get more complicated than that.

Is there a utility or script I could use to make this task easier? I work in Linux, so there should be plenty of possibilities, but I'm not really a hero with Perl et al.

Comment: This is screaming Emacs + AUCTeX at me. It should be noted that Emacs can be run in batch mode.

Comment: [Andraw Stacey](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey)’s [`mathgrep`](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/HowDidIDoThat/LaTeX/mathgrep.html) script should help here. Though, as it handels only `\( \)` and `\[ \]`, for inline math (`$`) you will need [replace often used Tex-Literals ($ and $$) for math regions into \( or \) and \[ or \]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46063) and/or [How to replace all $ $ by \( \)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118021)

Comment: Indeed. I admit to being lazy on this one and not having done my research properly. It deserved to be closed. Cheers!