# Can one redefine `$$` by `\[ ... \]`?

Tags: math-mode

Regardless of the purpose, I wonder whether one can redefine `$$` by `\[ ... \]`?

Comment: Not really, as `$$` forms part of `\[` and `\]`. Any reason why you want this?

Comment: Just feel that symbols are more attention-catching, nothing else.

Comment: This might not be your question exactly, but it is possible to do a global replace of `$$maths$$` with `\[maths\]` using regex. If that is your question then I'll make an answer explaining it!

Comment: Oh, really? Thank you very much, I am all ears! @PaulStiverson

Comment: Actually [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118303/80176) does a better job than I ever could!

Answer (score 0):

If `\(...\)` is close enough this there is great detail in the answers here: 
[Are \( and \) preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode/513#513)