# Latex find and replace

Tags: citing, texmaker

I want to avoid all reference quoting in my work. That is replace all [num] with null string. Deleting thousands of that manually is painstaking. Could a code be written for it.?
NB: i copy pasted the text and [num] came along with it. I want to remove those.
Texmaker is the editor I’m using.

Its looks like this

```
\chapter{name}

I just copied and pasted here and[2] came along with it. 
I want to remove that. I have created my work and it was in 
the end that it occurred to me there were unintended citations[3].
```

There’s a lot of `\chapter`s, `\section`s and `\subsection`s and to manually remove it by reading every para is tedious. So i was wondering if there’d be a code to help me solve this issue.

Comment: 1) You are really citing yourself thousands times?
2) Can't you just change the bibtex entry corresponding to your work to blank entries?
3) I don't get it, you're citing work actually writing, for example, `[4]`?
4) If 3) is true, most text editors allow for "find and replace" functionalities. Example, in texstudio (and most of editors), give a shot to `CTRL + R`

Comment: Welcome to the site. This seems not difficult. Can you please add a minimale example of your code.

Comment: Does that mean that the text in your `.tex` document (not only in the PDF output) already only contains `[4]` etc. and not `\cite{sigfridsson}`?

Comment: @moewe yes exactly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With texmaker you can use regular expression search/replace feature.  Initiate the replace via <kbd>CNTL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or select `Edit/Replace` from the pull down menu

[image]

Click the `+` button on the right and select `Regular Expression`.

[image]

In the `Find` dialog box enter `\[[0-9]*\]` and select `Replace All`.

[image]

This should delete all occurrences of text such as `[8]`, `[75]`, etc.

### Notes:

- Other options including using external tools to this are listed at [Automatically replace all |foo| with \abs{foo}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116036/4301).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\def\cite#1{\null}` to avoid all cite reference in the text but use `\nocite{*}`, otherwise your reference list will be empty.

`\nocite{*}` will show all the reference you have (cited/uncited)

Hopes this helps

Comment: Thanks. But i copy pasted the text and [num] was with it. I was wondering if there’d be a way remove those.

Comment: then you can use some regex to remove those. which editor are you using?

Comment: okay. But the thing is I have zero knowledge about latex and worse I have literally zero seconds before my deadline . So if it’d be fine could you tell me the whole code

Comment: which editor (fte/notepad/vim/ms word etc..) are you using, i will tell you the regex command to replace

Comment: texmaker that’s what your asking right?

Comment: yes!. Actually i am not familiar with that editor. Do you know vim?

Comment: Why don't you try https://typeset.io to format your paper. you can format your paper, even you have 0 knowledge in LaTeX

Comment: I’m sorry I’m not getting anything.

Comment: Please see the below link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432218/how-to-insert-submatches-from-regular-expression-in-texstudio

Comment: like that you can Find: [(\d+)]
Replace:

Comment: that’s not working. Its not even finding those square brackets.

Comment: \[(\d+)\] Is this works?

Comment: nope it doesn’t

Comment: @AswinPrasad I think you will have to give us a few more details about what you want to do and about what you are trying so far. (See also my comment under your question.) Firstly, it is still not clear to me how your source `.tex` file looks like. Do you have `[1]` in your source or real citations such as `\cite{sigfridsson}`? If you are trying `[\d+]` or similar to remove `[1]` and friends, do you even use an editor that has RegExp capabilities? You mentioned TeXmaker, which AFAIK doesn't do RegExp. So you would have to use a different editor.

Comment: @moewe i have like this [1] kind of citation. TexMaker is the editor i use but I don’t know if it has RegExp capabilities.