# How to make text look different in PDF compared to copy-paste

Tags: pdf, text, copy-paste

Is there a way to make text written in LateX look like something in the pdf document, but different if you copy-paste it?


Here is an example of what I would like:
In the pdf document: there is 10 km to the city
when you copy-paste:  there is 10 kilometers to the city

added after reply:
Thank you all.

However, I also want to do it when writing by using $$.

As an example again, If I write: for water $\rho$ is 997 $kg/m^3$

PDF: for water rho is 997 kg/m^3
copy-paste: for water the density is 997 kilograms per cubic meter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically replace all |foo| with \abs{foo}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116036/automatically-replace-all-foo-with-absfoo)

Comment: You can simply copy and paste in your TeX editor.

Comment: you can use accsupp or tagpdf for this. Both allow to add an /ActualText entry. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18509/2388

Comment: As far as I understand it, question "Automatically replace all |foo| with \abs{foo}" has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Thank you all. No "Automatically replace all |foo| with \abs{foo}" does not answer my question but thank you anyway. "use accsupp" does answer some of my question (or indeed the question I asked), Thank you, but I can see that I have to specify my question.

Answer (score 5):

This is doable with the `accsupp` package however be warned it only works on some PDF viewers. It works for me with Adobe Acrobat Pro, but not with Apple Preview. The general form is `\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={what gets pasted}} what gets copied \EndAccSupp{}` so we can define a `\km` command that will do what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\newcommand\km{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={kilometers}}km \EndAccSupp{}}

\begin{document}
there is 10 \km to the city
\end{document}
```

[image]

copy/pastes:

> there is 10 kilometers to the city