# How to make symbols (written by using $$), look like something in the pdf and different if you copy-paste it?

Tags: equations, pdf, copy-paste

Is there a way to make symbols, written by using the function $$, in LaTeX look like something in the pdf document, but different if you copy-paste it?

Here is an example of what I would like:
Something like this in my code: `For water $\rho$ is 997 $kg/m^3$` 
In the pdf document: For water ρ is 997 kg/m³ 
When you copy-paste: For water the density is 997 kilograms per cubic meter

(I asked a similar question some days ago and got some good answers. I was told to use ‘accsupp’, however, I can’t get it to work when using $$)

(added after i first asked the question:)
I have been asked for an example of my problem, here it comes. My code is:

```
\documentclass{article} \
\usepackage{accsupp} 

\newcommand\km{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={kilometers}}km \EndAccSupp{}} \
\newcommand\km{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={density}} $\rho$ \EndAccSupp{}} 

\begin{document} \
\km % when you make a PDF file, and copy-paste this part it will give you 'kilometers' and not 'km' 

\ $\rho$ % a bad try to do the same for '$\rho$' as for 'km' \
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this question about TeX, LaTeX, and friends, or is it about postscript and pdf programming?

Comment: For me the `accsupp` answer you got on the other question works fine for your `For water $\rho$ is 997 $kg/m^3$` example. If you can't get it to work, I think you should include a minimal example demonstrating your issue.

Comment: it is about Latex, when I say PDF files I mean PDF files made by using latex @Mico

Comment: I have included an example now @MarcelKrüger

Comment: When you compile your example code, you will get an error that you are defining `\km` twice. Please create an actually working example demonstrating your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make text look different in PDF compared to copy-paste](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622878/how-to-make-text-look-different-in-pdf-compared-to-copy-paste)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, and maybe I have just been stupid not to see what to do.
Here is the answer:

```
\documentclass{article} \
\usepackage{accsupp} 

\newcommand\km{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={kilometers}}km \EndAccSupp{}} \
\newcommand\rhox{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={density}} $\rho$ \EndAccSupp{}} 

\begin{document} \
\km % when you make a PDF file, and copy-paste this part it will give you 'kilometers' and not 'km' 

\rhox is ... % it works now

\end{document}
```