# How to convert $...$ to \(...\)

Tags: math-mode, syntax

So according to
[Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) and
[Are \( and \) preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode)
I should be using `\(...\)` instead of `$...$` and `\[...\]` instead of
`$$...$$`.

But what if I have a document where I've already used dollar signs a
bit? How do I convert them? A simple find and replace won't work since:

1. It won't care whether $$ is a beginning or ending; and
2. I use the dollar sign in the text (to refer to the currency).

Does anyone have a neat tip for this?

Comment: I don't think you should worry about `\( .. \)` right now, you can live with `$..$`. About the display math with a basic regular expressions it could work, search `\$\$([\s\S]+?)\$\$` and replace `\[\1\]`.

Comment: @Manuel Not with `sed` ...

Comment: If you do try using regular expressions ***back up first and do not destroy the back up at all soon***. Don't assume that if it mostly looks right, it is all right or that if this document looks right, that one probably is as well. I wouldn't do this at all except as I was editing unless I was absolutely confident I was not going to accidentally delete crucial bits of my document and turn others into garbage. `$$...$$` has been deprecated for 20+ years. If nothing terrible has happened by now, it isn't likely to do so tomorrow. Just start using the new syntax as you edit (`$...$` is OK.)

Comment: @cfr Yes, you are right. I just wrote something that has worked for me on an online regex and on my text editor. But of course there are more “versions”.

Comment: @Manuel It is just that I can imagine somebody unawares copying the magic incantation and... poof! Who know? I don't think the results of running that with `sed` would be at all happy.

Comment: for easier solution checkout  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/697738/201795

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will depend a lot on which editor you use and the features it provides so I doubt there will be a single answer; however, if you editor has good regex support then this should be pretty easy.

Here's how you can match for `$...$`

```pl
/\s\$(.|\n)+?\$/g
```

and similarly, matching for `$$...$$`:

```pl
/\s\$\$(.|\n)+?\$\$/g
```

This will not match the dollar signs as they have to be escaped with `\$` and the above pattern requires any of the whitespace characters before the dollar sign (space, tab or newline).  You can see a nice visualization for that [here](http://regexper.com/#%5Cs%5C%24(.%7C%5Cn)%2B%3F%5C%24) and [here](http://regexper.com/#%5Cs%5C%24%5C%24(.%7C%5Cn)%2B%3F%5C%24%5C%24) respectively.

If your editor supports the `s` flag from Perl, then you can simplify `(.|\n)+?` to just `.+?` as `.` will match new lines too.

Finally, putting it together with a substitution, you get:

```pl
s/(\s)\$(.+?)\$/\1\(\2\)/sg
```

*Note that I'm not escaping certain characters because it will depend on the particular implementation of regex.  In particular, the group parentheses may require `\(...\)` and the `+`, `?` and the backslashes in the replacement may also need to be escaped depending on which regex implementation you are using.*

If you are in the command line and have Perl, then the following two commands should do the trick:

```sh
perl -077pi.bak -e 's/(\s)\$\$(.+?)\$\$/\1\\[\2\\]/sg' document.tex
perl -077pi.bak -e 's/(\s)\$(.+?)\$/\1\\(\2\\)/sg' document.tex
```

Note that this will *not* match anything at the very start of the file; however, I don't think this will be a big issue as the start of the file will typically be a comment or at least `\documentclass`.

Comment: Rather crucially, some regex implementations require `\(...\)` for grouping. Not escaping those could have disastrous results. (`sed`, for example.)

Comment: @cfr Yeah, I'm aware and I mention that in the answer (though I probably should make it clearer).  There are so many regex implementation that I can't address them all

Comment: @JP-Ellis : you should copy your answer in [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46063/34551).

Comment: @Clément Thanks for the heads up.  I just copied the answer over.

Answer (score 8):

Single `$` are fine and supported syntax for inline math and even `$$` are mostly OK for display math. They are bad style but most of the time (if you are not using `fleqn`) they will give the same output as `\[..\]` so you can just change `$$` to `\[` as part of general editing as you edit the formulae, if you are not confident with regular expression replaces there is no pressing need to do a global edit of the document which may do more harm than good if you get the regular expression wrong. So try to use `\[` going forward but don't lose sleep over `$$` already in your document:-)

Comment: could you add your answer to the original, unduplicated question? this is really the right approach, imnsho.