# Automatically change l to \ell in a math mode

Tags: catcodes

I want to find a way how to automatically change "`l`" into "`\ell`" in a math mode.

I tried to do it using `\catcode`, but it's quite difficult for me.

I want it to change "`l`" only when it appears alone.

(e.g., do not change "`l`" in `\log` or if I define a variable `lb` as follows:

```
\[\log l = lb + l^2\]
```

I want to change the second and the fourth "`l`" only)

It would be even better if I can typeset the original "`l`" by using "`\ell`" instead (i.e., change the role of them)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that, in math mode, `lb` represents the multiplication of `l` and `b`, not the variable `lb`.  For multi-letter mathematical symbols, one might use, for example, `\mathrm{lb}`.  In this sense, your question might be considered ambiguous.

Comment: I think this question has already been answered by Lev Bishop in [Substituting character $l$ with $\ell$ throughout math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/substituting-character-l-with-ell-throughout-math-mode?rq=1)

Comment: 1/ Thanks a lot for pointing out why this is hard.

2/ Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A proof of concept. You need to mark up the multiletter variables anyway, because you don't want that your reader mistake them for products.

```
\documentclass{article}

\mathchardef\standardl=\mathcode`l
\mathcode`l=\ell
\newcommand{\deactivatel}{\mathcode`l=\standardl}
\makeatletter
\edef\operator@font{\operator@font\noexpand\deactivatel}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mlvar}[1]{\mathit{\deactivatel #1}}

\begin{document}

\[
\log l+\mlvar{lb}+l^2
\]

\end{document}
```

The letter `l` is assigned as mathcode the one of `\ell`. But in some places (operators and multiletter variables) it is set back to the original.

[image]

However, you should use `\ell` when you want it (and in my opinion one *never* needs it).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems the best I can do with pdf latex.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. The solution provides a Lua function called `l2ell` that does most of the actual work, along with two utility LaTeX macros, `\lellOff` and `\lellOn`, which deactivate and reactivate the `l2ell` function.

This approach will admittedly go astray on `$\l$`. However, as `\l` is a text-mode command (for the Polish "soft ell", to be specific), it shouldn't occur in math-y circumstances, right?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
   function l2ell ( s )
      s = s:gsub ( "^l(%A)" , "\\ell %1" )
      s = s:gsub ( "(%A)l$" , "%1\\ell" )
      s = s:gsub ( "(%A)l(%A)" , "%1\\ell %2" )
      return s 
   end
\end{luacode}

%  LaTeX macros to activate and deactivate the Lua function:
\newcommand\lellOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback ( 
  "process_input_buffer" , l2ell , "l2ell" )}}
\newcommand\lellOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback ( 
  "process_input_buffer" , "l2ell" )}}
\AtBeginDocument{\lellOn} % activate the Lua function by default
  
\begin{document}
$\log l +\ln l= lb + l^2$, $l$, $ll$, $l + l$, $ l ^ l$

\lellOff % deactivate the Lua function
$\log l +\ln l= lb + l^2$, $l$, $ll$, $l + l$, $ l ^ l$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Really awesome! (except for the fact that I have to figure out how to compile my tex file with LuaLaTeX). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user182849 - Which front-end editor do you use? If it has a drop-down menu to select which program to run, chances are that "lualatex" will be one of the options.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I am using texmaker, and now I have figured out how to compile it with lualatex! Your solution works well. I should read some articles like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28642/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-lualatex before moving to LuaLaTeX, though:)